# Drop barcode character on scanning

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have android an application with a bar-code scanner in the main activity. After scanning the bar-code I search for this number in a database.

My problem is that when I scan the bar-code, not all characters are read. For example, if I try to scan `807251306246`, after scanning this bar-code, one or two characters are randomly removed.

I tried to create a new application that reads the bar-code and views it in a list. It works fine. I use the same code in both apps.

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et;
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                barcodeInserted();
                return true;
            } else if (i== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
public void barcodeInserted() {
   tv.append(et.getText().toString()+"\n");
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.barcode.barcodescanner.MainActivity">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the enter key

Comment: The number is stored as int or string? the deleted numbers are deleted from the end or random places in the number?

Comment: @dave no, that work as a keyboard. the focus stay on the same edit text

Comment: @FlyingNades string but this not matter, random place.

Comment: Show us the code you are using then, the barcode reader should send at least an end of line character once it has scanned.

Comment: @dave code has been added

Comment: This is far from a barcode scanner, that's a raw text user input. can we get the xml please?

Comment: @FlyingNades XML code added

Answer (score 0):

This code accepts input into an edittext and waits for the end of the input

```
etInput.requestFocus();
        etInput.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                String fString = etInput.getText().toString().replace("\n", "");
                processScan(fString);
            }
            etInput.setText("");
            etInput.requestFocus();
            return false;
        });
```

Where process scan is where you should do your lookup work.

Comment: The same result.

Comment: Then its a setting on your barcode scanner,  this code is implemented in an industrial app and gets called about 8000 times a day :-)